# Replacing [splash] tag with something more useful

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I've been using this framework from scrapinghub, [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash). It's a "A JavaScript rendering service" and it has its own documentation [here](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This framework uses an adaptation of [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) which in most cases can't be asked in the Lua tag.

I was trying to find somewhere to solve my coding problems, but very few people wander around the issue tracker in the repository, and I do believe that issue trackers should be for framework bugs/features rather than programming problems that people face.

So I searched for the tag on Stack Overflow, but I came across [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash). I think this tag is pretty useless; only 340 questions are tagged and from a search point of view it's not ground-breaking to replace it with something that has room to expand documentation and help others in a more impactful way.

Am I missing something or is this doable?

Comment: What is unclear in this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need some disambiguation.

The tag info for [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash) says it's about splash screens, not about the JavaScript rendering service. However, we also have the tag [splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash-screen) which fulfills the same purpose.

Then there is the [scrapy-splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy-splash) tag that is about integrating Scrapy with Splash.
And there is the [scrapinghub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapinghub) about the company that made JavaScript rendering service called Splash.

Here's my proposal:

1. Since we don't like company names as tags, I suggest that we create [scrapinghub-splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapinghub-splash) and apply it to questions about Scrapinghub's Splash framework. We then remove [scrapinghub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapinghub).
2. We also apply [splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash-screen) to the questions about splash screens, and remove [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash).
3. Then finally we would add a DO NOT USE on the [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash), and tell  what tags should be used instead - splash-screen, scrapinghub-splash and scrapy-splash.